# How to activate Request Scope outside of a real request in a spring MVC application?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc application which make massive use of beans which are defined in a
request scope. Now I have to use a part of this application outside of this scope (in a
qwertz job in the Magnolia CMS). This doesn't work of course:

> Error creating bean with name 'requestHelper': Scope 'request' is 
>   not active for the current thread

I can't change the scope of the beans and I can't change the code. So my only possibility
seems to change the scope of the current thread to a request scope mockup.

I tried something like

```
XmlWebApplicationContext context = (XmlWebApplicationContext) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext() ;
   MockServletContext mockServletContext = new MockServletContext("/");
   context.setServletContext(mockServletContext);
   context.refresh();
```

But this still doesn't activate the request scope in the current thread. How can I achieve
  this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request scope can be activated as follows:

```
RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(
    new ServletRequestAttributes(new MockHttpServletRequest()));     

...

((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
    .requestCompleted();
RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
```

Thoguh I think it's not a good idea to use such a hack in production code.

Comment: I have to use it in a productive environment. Why do you think it's a bad idea?